# Aligning the Top of Text in Two Divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm currently trying to figure out how to align the top of text for two div boxes. The wrapper div is one box and within that I have two other div boxes inside that are beside one another. I want the top of the header text to align with the top of the paragraph text (photo attached). The code below is what I have right now, and the image attached is what I'm wanting. I've tried 'vertical-align:top' but it's not working. Any ideas?
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Htm.png)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
  
#box1, #box2 {
    vertical-align: top;
}

#box1 {
    background: #00FFFF;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: right;
}

#box2 {
    background: #FF00FF;
    width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <p>Paragraph goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: remove margin from p and h1

Answer (score 1):

just remove the margin on h1

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
  
#box1, #box2 {
    vertical-align: top;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

#box1 {
    background: #00FFFF;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: right;
}

#box2 {
    background: #FF00FF;
    width: 65%;
}
h1{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <p>Paragraph goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```